# LISTAGG: group within group

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me start with data to better describe what I need. I have a table called SUPERMARKET with the following fields:

```
Field 1: StoreID
Field 2: ProductCategory
Field 3: ProductID
```

The data will look like this:

```
1, Fruit, Banana
1, Fruit, PineApple
1, Fruit, Strawberry
1, Beverage, Milk
1, Beverage, Chocolate Milk
1, Beverage, Apple Juice
1, Vegetable, beet
2, Vegetable, beet
2, Vegetable, onion
2, Vegetable, Kyle
```

And I would like to have a view like this:

```
1, Fruit:(Banana, PineApple, Strawberry), Beverage:(Milk, Chocolate Milk, Apple Juice), Vegetable: (beet)
2, Vegetable:(beet, onion, kyle)
```

Does Oracle have a way to display the information I was looking for as described above? I have tried:

```
SELECT "StoreID", LISTAGG("ProductCategory",',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ProductCategory") "ProductCategories" FROM SUPERMARKET GROUP BY "StoreID"
```

But this one only lists:

```
1, "Fruit,Beverage,Vegetable"
2, "Vegetable"
```

or if I use ProductID instead of ProductCategory then I get a list of product displayed randomly and not grouped by category

```
SELECT "StoreID", LISTAGG("ProductID",',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ProductID") "Products" FROM SUPERMARKET GROUP BY "StoreID"
```

Does anyone have a trick how to solve this? Please help.

***UPDATE AND ISSUE WITH VIEW:***

The sql suggested by everyone works like a charm until I tried to put the exact same working sql into a view. For some reason, Oracle compiler does not like it and throws out error:

```
Error(s) parsing SQL:
Unexpected token near *!* in the following:
|| ')', ', ') WITHIN *!*GROUP (
Unexpected token near *!* in the following:
|| ')', ', ') WITHIN GROUP *!*(
Missing expression near *!* in the following:
|| ')', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (
*!*ORDER BY ProductCategory) AS ProductsAndCategories
```

Does anyone knows why? Since it is related to my original question, I thought I would put it in the same question for easy reference in future.

[image]

***Suggestion from Gordon***:

This is actually a bug from SQL Developer GUI. To bypass the issue ->Create view using statement .

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful

Comment: Using statements to create the view worked for me. The UI way didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT storeId,
       LISTAGG(ProductCategory || ':' || '(' || ProductIds || ')', ', ')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ProductCategory) as ProductsAndCategories
FROM (SELECT StoreId, ProductCategory,
             LISTAGG(ProductId, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ProductId) as ProductIds
      FROM SUPERMARKET
      GROUP BY StoreId, ProductCategory
     ) s
GROUP BY StoreId;
```

Comment: The SQL you suggested worked perfectly... until I put it in a view and Oracle compiler generated weird error. Are we not supposed to put listagg in view?

Comment: @user1205746 . . . I just created on in Oracle and it worked fine.  (I wouldn't expect there to be a limitation on this.)

Comment: Ok, Gordon. I will try again and see what I might have missed. I have tried multiple times before I bugged you... Hmm..

Comment: Yeah.. it is definitely an issue for me. Not sure why. I have updated the question with a screen capture. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT storeid,
  listagg(a,',') within GROUP (
ORDER BY a)
FROM
  (SELECT storeid,
    productCategory
    ||'('
    ||listagg(productId,',') within GROUP (
  ORDER BY productId)
    ||')' a
  FROM supermarket
  GROUP BY storeid,
    productCategory
  )
GROUP BY storeid
```